# Publishing JUnit results from Jenkins to SonarQube not on same server

Tags: jenkins, junit, sonarqube

I've got the following setup:

- server 192.168.0.xxx running Jenkins 1.643
- server 192.168.0.yyy running SonarQube 5.2 (with Java 1.8.0_66)
- server 192.168.0.zzz running PostgreSQL as SonarQube DB (FYI)

I want Jenkins to run a SonarQube analysis on a specific project. I therefore created a job with goal `sonar:sonar -Dsonar.host.url=http://192.168.0.yyy`. Everything's working well except for code coverage in SonarQube. It says there's a coverage of 0,0 % although there are several tests run by Jenkins.

So I'm pretty sure test results are not published to SonarQube. Google brought me to solutions exporting the results to a directory on the same server and telling SonarQube this directory via `-Dsonar.junit.reportsPath`.

But this solution is not that easy to implement having Jenkins and SonarQube not on the same server. Long story short: is there another way publishing JUnit test results to SonarQube?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The report path should point to a directory where the *analysis* is run not on the sonarqube *server*

So when you are running the sonar:sonar command just use the `-Dsonar.junit.reportsPath` to point to the the directory containing the report of unit test execution and you should be fine.

Comment: Thank you for bringing light into the darkness! I tried running `test` as mvn goal before and it worked fine. Full mvn goal: `test sonar:sonar -Dsonar.host.url=http://192.168.0.yyy`

Comment: I accepted but could not upvote due to my reputation score lower 15. Will do it when I'm able to (: